# Youtube ytplayer

Tags: javascript, api, youtube

I am trying to insert a Youtube video on my website using these code:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
var player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
  height: '450',
  width: '800',
  videoId: 'myvideoID',
});
};
```

But where I am supposed to set rel=0 to do not have suggestions when the video had finished ?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simply append this to the "videoId" so:

player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
  height: '450',
  width: '800',
  videoId: 'myvideoID?rel=0',
});

Answer (score 0):

It is an attribute on the player object. Simply add it as a new line. Other things like autoplay, modestBranding, etc. will follow the same style.

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);  
var player; 
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() { 
  player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
    height: '450',
    width: '800',
    videoId: 'myvideoID',
    rel: 0
  });
};
```

I've built an app that uses the YouTube Data and Player API, feel free to take what you need: https://github.com/HunterMeyer/YouTV/blob/master/js/scripts.js